# CGRectのログ出力

Tags: ios, objective-c

CGRect使ったコーディングで、x,y,w,h座標をログ出力するときに楽に出力出来る方法はありませんでしょうか？

Comment: Objective-CかSwiftか、区別してくださいませ。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。Objective-Cのタグを追加しました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(hoge);
```

とすると楽に出力できますよ

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
これ便利ですね。